# Basic text editor in Python with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have finished writing my nice and little text editor in Python with Tkinter.
I tried to achieve the best user experience that I could.

- I want this code to be 2/3 compatible, I tested it in both versions but if you could test it out again in the 2 versions too it would very knd of you.
- I did not use a class on purpose because I think that there is no need for it in such a small project (< 100 lines), do you think I should use classes also in small projects like this?
- Is the user going to use this without problems?
- Is the code going to be readable if I look back at it after, let's say, a year?
- Do I use good names?
- I did not use a `__name__` guard because this file is not meant to be imported, do you think I should use it anyway?
- What other features could I implement?

The code:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

try:
    import tkMessageBox as pop_up
except:
    import tkinter.tkMessageBox as pop_up

import time

EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_SAVE = "Please write the name of the file you want to save in the given field."
EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_OPEN = "Please write the name of the file you want to open in the given field."
FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_MESSAGE = "No file with the given title was found, remember that this text editor can only read files in its directory."
SAVING_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Your text is now stored in the {filename} file"
SIGNATURE_TXT_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "Please be sure that the file you want to open exists and that it is in the same folder of this editor."


def _open():
    if not file_title.get():
        pop_up.showerror("Title is empty.",EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_OPEN)
        return 1

    if not ".txt" in file_title.get():
        filename = file_title.get() + ".txt"

    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            main_text.delete("1.0",tk.END)
            main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, f.read(), "a")
    except IOError:
        pop_up.showerror("File not found.",FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_MESSAGE)

def save():
    if not file_title.get():
        pop_up.showerror("No title.",EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_SAVE)
        return 1

    if not ".txt" in file_title.get():
        filename = file_title.get() + ".txt"

    with open(filename,"w+") as f:
        f.write(main_text.get(1.0,tk.END))
    pop_up.showinfo("File saved succesfully.",SAVING_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.format(filename=filename))

def add_date():
    full_date = time.localtime()
    day = str(full_date.tm_mday)
    month = str(full_date.tm_mon)
    year = str(full_date.tm_year)
    date = "\n"+day+'/'+month+'/'+year
    main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, date, "a")

def add_signature():
    try:
        with open("signature.txt") as f:
            main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, "\n"+f.read(), "a")
    except IOError:
        MESSAGE = SIGNATURE_TXT_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE
        pop_up.showerror("\"signature.txt\" not found.",MESSAGE)  

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
menubar.add_command(label="Save", command=save)
menubar.add_command(label="Add signature",command=add_signature)
menubar.add_command(label="Add date",command=add_date)


root.config(menu=menubar)

top = tk.Frame(root)
temp = tk.Label(root,text="Title:")
temp.pack(in_ = top,side=tk.LEFT)

file_title = tk.Entry(root)
file_title.pack(in_ = top,side=tk.RIGHT)

top.pack()

main_text = tk.Text(root)
main_text.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific questions:

> I did not use a class on purpose because I think that there is no need for it in such a small project (< 100 lines), do you think I should use classes also in small projects like this?

This is fine without classes, but on the other hand anything of any meaningful complexity will be much easier as OOP; why not have a go at rewriting this to use a class for the UI and see how it goes?

> Is the user going to use this without problems?

I'd have thought so, but instructions and a test plan wouldn't go amiss!

> Is the code going to be readable if I look back at it after, let's say, a year?

It would be nice to see some [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), but this is a pretty simple script and I expect you'd be able to follow it.

> Do I use good names?

Mostly; see the other answers and below for exceptions, but it's generally clear what's going on. You could put all the boilerplate messages into a single dictionary to clean up the namespace a bit, too.

> I did not use a `__name__` guard because this file is not meant to be imported, do you think I should use it anyway?

Yes, it's good practice and you may later change your mind and `import` at least part of it.

> What other features could I implement?

That is outside the scope of CodeReview, but what features do *you like* in a text editor?

---

Bare `except` is a very bad practice; if something unexpected goes wrong, you have no way of knowing what. Instead, be specific:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
```

You could alternatively consider:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    import tkinter as tk
    ...
else:
    import Tkinter as tk
    ...
```

This makes it more explicit what's going on.

---

The leading underscore on `_open` suggests that it should be considered private. I doubt this is your intention; if you just wanted to avoid the name conflict with the built-in function, the convention is a *trailing* underscore `open_`.

---

`Tkinter` comes with handy dialogs for loading and saving files: see `tkFileDialog`/`tkinter.filedialog`.

Answer (score 5):

**Style**

Python has a guide style called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). If you have no good reason not to follow it, just follow it. You'll find various tools to check your code ([pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8), [pep8online.com/](http://pep8online.com/), etc) and even to fix it more or less automatically ([autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/1.0.4)).

Here's a list of problems detected :

```
txt_original.py:13:80: E501 line too long (105 > 79 characters)
txt_original.py:14:80: E501 line too long (105 > 79 characters)
txt_original.py:15:80: E501 line too long (141 > 79 characters)
txt_original.py:17:80: E501 line too long (138 > 79 characters)
txt_original.py:22:43: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:25:8: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
txt_original.py:30:35: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:33:43: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:35:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
txt_original.py:37:37: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:40:8: E713 test for membership should be 'not in'
txt_original.py:43:23: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:44:34: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:45:46: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:45:80: E501 line too long (95 > 79 characters)
txt_original.py:47:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
txt_original.py:55:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 1
txt_original.py:61:56: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:61:65: W291 trailing whitespace
txt_original.py:68:42: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:69:37: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:75:21: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:76:14: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
txt_original.py:76:16: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
txt_original.py:76:20: E231 missing whitespace after ','
txt_original.py:79:20: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
txt_original.py:79:22: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
txt_original.py:79:26: E231 missing whitespace after ','
```

And here's you code after most of the problems are fixed :

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk

try:
    import tkMessageBox as pop_up
except:
    import tkinter.tkMessageBox as pop_up

import time

EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_SAVE = "Please write the name of the file you want to save in the given field."
EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_OPEN = "Please write the name of the file you want to open in the given field."
FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_MESSAGE = "No file with the given title was found, remember that this text editor can only read files in its directory."
SAVING_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = "Your text is now stored in the {filename} file"
SIGNATURE_TXT_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = "Please be sure that the file you want to open exists and that it is in the same folder of this editor."


def _open():
    if not file_title.get():
        pop_up.showerror("Title is empty.", EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_OPEN)
        return 1

    if ".txt" not in file_title.get():
        filename = file_title.get() + ".txt"

    try:
        with open(filename) as f:
            main_text.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, f.read(), "a")
    except IOError:
        pop_up.showerror("File not found.", FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_MESSAGE)


def save():
    if not file_title.get():
        pop_up.showerror("No title.", EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_SAVE)
        return 1

    if ".txt" not in file_title.get():
        filename = file_title.get() + ".txt"

    with open(filename, "w+") as f:
        f.write(main_text.get(1.0, tk.END))
    pop_up.showinfo(
        "File saved succesfully.",
        SAVING_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.format(
            filename=filename))


def add_date():
    full_date = time.localtime()
    day = str(full_date.tm_mday)
    month = str(full_date.tm_mon)
    year = str(full_date.tm_year)
    date = "\n" + day + '/' + month + '/' + year
    main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, date, "a")

def add_signature():
    try:
        with open("signature.txt") as f:
            main_text.insert(tk.INSERT, "\n" + f.read(), "a")
    except IOError:
        MESSAGE = SIGNATURE_TXT_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE
        pop_up.showerror("\"signature.txt\" not found.", MESSAGE)

root = tk.Tk()

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
menubar.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
menubar.add_command(label="Save", command=save)
menubar.add_command(label="Add signature", command=add_signature)
menubar.add_command(label="Add date", command=add_date)


root.config(menu=menubar)

top = tk.Frame(root)
temp = tk.Label(root, text="Title:")
temp.pack(in_=top, side=tk.LEFT)

file_title = tk.Entry(root)
file_title.pack(in_=top, side=tk.RIGHT)

top.pack()

main_text = tk.Text(root)
main_text.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

As I am talking about tools, it is probably worth mentionning that you'll find various other tools to check your code.

[pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) finds :

```
************* Module txt
C: 13, 0: Line too long (105/80) (line-too-long)
C: 14, 0: Line too long (105/80) (line-too-long)
C: 15, 0: Line too long (141/80) (line-too-long)
C: 17, 0: Line too long (138/80) (line-too-long)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
W:  3, 0: No exception type(s) specified (bare-except)
F:  4, 4: Unable to import 'Tkinter' (import-error)
W:  8, 0: No exception type(s) specified (bare-except)
F:  7, 4: Unable to import 'tkMessageBox' (import-error)
E:  9, 4: No name 'tkMessageBox' in module 'tkinter' (no-name-in-module)
F:  9, 4: Unable to import 'tkinter.tkMessageBox' (import-error)
C: 20, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 29,31: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C: 36, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 44,33: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C: 52, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 61, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
C: 63,38: Invalid variable name "f" (invalid-name)
C: 66, 8: Invalid variable name "MESSAGE" (invalid-name)
C: 69, 0: Invalid constant name "root" (invalid-name)
C: 71, 0: Invalid constant name "menubar" (invalid-name)
C: 80, 0: Invalid constant name "top" (invalid-name)
C: 81, 0: Invalid constant name "temp" (invalid-name)
C: 84, 0: Invalid constant name "file_title" (invalid-name)
C: 89, 0: Invalid constant name "main_text" (invalid-name)
```

but there is also pyflakes, pychecker, etc.

**Logic around file name**

The following logic :

```
if not ".txt" in file_title.get():
    filename = file_title.get() + ".txt"
```

seems wrong on many different levels :

1. It does not follow PEP8 and should be `if ".txt" not in file_title.get()`
2. You have the same hardcoded string in multiple places : you are pretty much asking to be biten at some point if you want to change this. What about `TXT_EXTENSION = '.txt'`.
3. You are calling `file_title.get()` for no good reason
4. You do not define `filename` if the condition in the `if` is evaluated to false. Maybe you meant :

   TXT_EXTENSION = '.txt'
   filename = file_title.get()
   if TXT_EXTENSION not in filename:
       filename = filename + TXT_EXTENSION
5. You are changing "toto.tutu" to "toto.tutu.txt" but "toto.txt.tutu" does not change. If what you are interested in is extension, you should probably be using [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

   6. You have the same logic in multiple places : you should probably move it in a function of its own :

   def add_txt_extension_if_needed(filename):
       if not filename.endswith(TXT_EXTENSION):
           return filename + TXT_EXTENSION
       return filename

**Date format**

You can probably find in the documentation how to format a date as a string.

*I have to go and I don't know tkinter but I guess other people will have additional relevant comments.*

Answer (score 3):

A few comments on top of [@Josay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9452/josay)'s excellent review.

---

In this code:

> ```
> if not file_title.get():
>     pop_up.showerror("Title is empty.",EMPTY_TITLE_ERROR_MESSAGE_OPEN)
>     return 1
>
> if not ".txt" in file_title.get():
>     filename = file_title.get() + ".txt"
> ```

There are 3 calls to `file_title.get()`.
If you expect the returned value to be the same (I'm pretty sure yes),
then it would be better to call it once and save in a variable.
This is a good practice,
not only as an optimization to reduce the number of calls,
but also for extensibility:
if you need to change something later,
you will be do it in one place instead of 3.

And why do you `return 1`? What is the `1` for?
If you mean to indicate "failure", then better to return `False`.
But since you never return `True`,
and the return value is not checked anywhere, you can just drop the "1" and `return` without argument.

You should also move all the code out of the global namespace and into a method,
for example `main`, and call that method like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```